# Compare Range between tables in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables CENTER and RANGE_CENTER. Based on the CENTER_ID from table 1 I need to find its corresponding ID.

Eg if Centreid is 2000 then it should display a100.Same way for all the records in table 1.

I am finding it difficult to write the query.

Could you please guide me on this.

```
DEPT    Center_Id
10  2000
10  2001
20  3001
20  2580


CENTER_FROM     CENTER_TO   ALLOCATION_ID
1999              2499       a100
2500              2999       b234
3000              3499       c199
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can `join` the tables so the center_id from one table is `between` the center_from and center_to from the other table.

```
select c.dept,c.center_id,rc.allocation_id
from center c
join range_center rc on c.center_id between rc.center_from and rc.center_to
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any other way we can write without using Join.

Comment: you can use `case` expressions with hard-coded ranges.

Comment: @Mani - not using a JOIN for a query with two tables is an extremely peculiar requirement.  You need to justify the restriction

Comment: No it is not the requirement from the client side. Join on one column is a little problem for me as I did not mention the complete structure of the table.If it is possible to do please let me knw

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like joins, then you can use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.DEPT, c.Center_Id,
       ( SELECT ALLOCATION_ID FROM RANGE_CENTER r
         WHERE c.Center_Id BETWEEN r.CENTER_FROM AND r.CENTER_TO
       ) As ALLOCATION_ID
FROM CENTER c
```

Comment: This is fine ,I just need to restrict row where it return more than one values in that subquery

Comment: kordirko: I am gettign multiple rows from subquery ,I need to display only those which are retriving single row

Comment: Thie error means, that `RANGE_CENTER` contains overlapping ranges. In this case the only way is to join both tables.